# Admob Rewarded Video If the user closes the video without watching it

Tags: android, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm using WebView and I've set everything up. If the user goes to the site called X, the ads appear. If the user closes the ad without tracking it, I want the WebView page to go back one step. How can I do that? I thought about adding it to the onRewardedVideoAdClosed() side, but the users who are successful in video playback are also taking a step back.

```
  @Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() { 
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reklam sayfası kapatıldı.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
    webView.goBack(); //doesn't work
}
```

---

```
 private void loadRewardedVideoAd() { 
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}


@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Başarılı! İçerik görüntüleme hakkı kazandınız. " ,/*+ reward.getType() + "  amount: " + reward.getAmount(),*/ Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Reward the user.

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reklam sayfası kapatıldı.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reklam yükelmesi başarısız oldu.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Geçiş reklamları hazır.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Geçiş reklamı açıldı.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Geçiş reklamı başladı.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reklam bitti.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.resume(getActivity());
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.pause(getActivity());
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mRewardedVideoAd.destroy(getActivity());
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remember, if the user earned the reward. The following code is based on the new API, but it should be trivial to implement this idea with the old API.

```
        RewardedAdCallback adCallback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
            boolean rewardEarned = false;

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                // Ad opened.
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                loadAd();
                showResponse(rewardEarned ? R.string.rewardEarned : R.string.adAborted);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem reward) {
                rewardEarned = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int errorCode) {
                // Ad failed to display
            }
        };
```